# How to insert 1 million records faster in MongoDb with Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have copy and paste to achieve 1 million records. Is there a faster way? I cannot use 100000 in the for..loop. The command prompt of Window 10 will be forzen.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    assert = require('assert');

var colName = 'students';
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/school', function(err, db) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    console.log("Successfully connected to MongoDB.");

    var collection = db.collection(colName);

    db.listCollections().toArray(function(err, collections) {
            if (err) console.log(err);

            var result = collections.some(function(coll) {
                if (coll.name == colName) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

            if (result) {
                console.log(colName+" FOUND.");
                collection.drop(function(err, delOK) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    if (delOK) console.log(colName+" Collection deleted");
                    db.close();
                });             
            } else {
                console.log("NOT FOUND.");
                db.close();
            }
        });
});

var fc = 10000;
var counter = 0;

//create 10,000 records
function inputStudents(lastCount) {
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/school', function(err, db) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        console.log("Successfully connected to MongoDB.");

        var collection = db.collection(colName);
        var types = ['exam', 'quiz', 'homework', 'homework'];

        var maxReq = 10000;
        var finalCount = lastCount * 10;

        // 10,000 students
        for (i = 0; i < maxReq; i++) {

            // take 10 classes
            for (class_counter = 0; class_counter < 10; class_counter ++) {
                scores = []
                    // and each class has 4 grades
                    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                        scores.push({'type':types[j],'score':Math.random()*100});
                    }

                // there are 500 different classes that they can take
                class_id = Math.floor(Math.random()*501); // get a class id between 0 and 500

                record = {'student_id':i, 'scores':scores, 'class_id':class_id};
                collection.insertOne(record, function(err, res) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        counter++;
                        console.log("counter: "+counter);
                        if (counter == finalCount) db.close();
                    });
            }
        }   
    });
}

//wait 10 seconds, 1
setTimeout(function afterTenSeconds() {
    inputStudents(fc+counter);
}, 10000);

//wait 2m, 2
setTimeout(function afterTenSeconds() {
    inputStudents(fc+counter);
}, 2*60*1000);

//wait 4m, 3
setTimeout(function afterTenSeconds() {
    inputStudents(fc+counter);
}, 4*60*1000);

//wait 6m, 4
setTimeout(function afterTenSeconds() {
    inputStudents(fc+counter);
}, 6*60*1000);

//wait 8m, 5
setTimeout(function afterTenSeconds() {
    inputStudents(fc+counter);
}, 8*60*1000);

//wait 10m, 6
setTimeout(function afterTenSeconds() {
    inputStudents(fc+counter);
}, 10*60*1000);

//wait 12m, 7
setTimeout(function afterTenSeconds() {
    inputStudents(fc+counter);
}, 12*60*1000);

//wait 14m, 8
setTimeout(function afterTenSeconds() {
    inputStudents(fc+counter);
}, 14*60*1000);

//wait 16m, 9
setTimeout(function afterTenSeconds() {
    inputStudents(fc+counter);
}, 16*60*1000);

//wait 18m, 10
setTimeout(function afterTenSeconds() {
    inputStudents(fc+counter);
}, 18*60*1000);
```

I have to copy and paste for each one, 2 minutes gap. Is there a way to connect the callback? I cannot let them run at the same time. I will get < 1 million records because db.close will chop off some records.

Comment: Does it have to go through NodeJS? There are bulk-load commandline tools that can read from CSV or JSON files.

Comment: Teacher gave us code in the older version. I cannot run it with new nodeJS. I convert it to the newer version.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [bulk](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/anintroductionto1_4_and_2_6.html#ordered-unordered-bulk-operations) inserts.

There are two types of bulk operations:

1. Ordered bulk operations. These operations execute all the operation in order and error out on the first write error.
2. Unordered bulk operations. These operations execute all the operations in parallel and aggregates up all the errors. Unordered bulk operations do not guarantee order of execution.

So you can do something like this:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://myserver:27017/test", function(err, db) {
// Get the collection
var col = db.collection('myColl');

// Initialize the Ordered Batch
// You can use initializeUnorderedBulkOp to initialize Unordered Batch
var batch = col.initializeOrderedBulkOp();

// take 10 classes
        for (class_counter = 0; class_counter < 10; class_counter ++) {
            scores = []
                // and each class has 4 grades
                for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    scores.push({'type':types[j],'score':Math.random()*100});
                }

            // there are 500 different classes that they can take
            class_id = Math.floor(Math.random()*501); // get a class id between 0 and 500

            record = {'student_id':i, 'scores':scores, 'class_id':class_id};
  batch.insert(record);
}

// Execute the operations
batch.execute(function(err, result) {
  console.dir(err);
  console.dir(result);
  db.close();
});
});
```

I mean something like this, I haven't executed the code, so I am not sure it will work but you will understand what I am trying to say.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, bulk.insert is extreme fast. My old code got 1:34. The new one is 0:57, less than a minute.

Comment: New test: code become very slow after 2 Millions.

Comment: @HomanHuang u can mark this answer as it helped u in getting the code fast, Also because this post is marked as duplicate, I cannot make another answer to the post, but I will tell u another way to insert for more than 2 millions record, u can write a bash script and make the insertion directly using that bash script. It will be way faster